# I got stuck in this anti ads link with blacklist role

Tags: discord.py

I starting to learning discord.py and I got some idea to make a anti advertising link function. My plan is detect a link that have http or https in link they send and give they a role and in my plan this role name is gg and this is my code

```
#Advertising link detection
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'https' in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} This link not ALLOWED")

    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'http' in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} This link not ALLOWED")
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)


#autorole
autorole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='gg')
await ctx.add.roles(autorole)
```

I really no idea how to do this function

Comment: What about your code is not working?

Comment: I can't give blacklist role to people who sent ads link

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No I can delete message with ads and no error but my problem is I don't know how to add blacklist role to people who send ads link

Comment: Well you have the code for that at the bottom of your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your code you have two functions with the same name, so the second one overrides the first one and only the second one is used and the first one is discarded. Most of the time situations like this can be avoided by using a single event with the code combined. in your case that would work too using a elif or the `or` keyword. so

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'https' in message.content.lower() or 'http' in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} This link not ALLOWED")

    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

but I would highly suggest using regex to match for urls

Comment: Also he would need to add the auto role after the await.channel.send(..) if I understood it right

Answer (score 0):

You have called same event 2 times and that causes bot to stuck use else if two add 2 if statement

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 events

```py
on_message(message):
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.